# Hooking a sony vaio to tv

Tags: laptop

I am trying to hook a sony vaio pcg-grt250p laptop to a television that only has svideo. Now the laptop only has one video out I looked on sony's site at the manual to double check. Its a 3.5mm video out. I am wanting to purchase the cable but I'm not sure what to search for as I haven't seen that type of output before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The A/V-out jack is probably a 3.5mm 4-pole jack.  There are matching cables with a 4-pole plug on one end and three RCA plugs (color coded yellow, red & white) on the other end.  But the yellow plug for composite video would also require a converter to S-Video.

Comment: Agrees with sawdust, that is what sony used on thier cameras.

Comment: ok awesome your the man!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the pin-out for that 3.5mm 4-pole video out port:

[image: Pin assignments]

```
Pin     Sony pinout
1       Left Audio
2       Composite Video
3       A&V Ground
4       Right Audio
```

[Pin-out info source](http://pinoutsguide.com/Home/av_jack_pinout.shtml)

But that's only going to get you composite video (yellow RCA), where you say you need s-video (4-pin DIN connector).

Since that notebook appears to only have VGA (and that weird video out port ;) ) you could consider a VGA-to-SVideo/Composite adapter.

Here's [an example (by StarTech)](http://www.startech.com/AV/Converters/Video/High-Resolution-VGA-to-Composite-or-S-Video-Converter~VGA2VID):

> This High Resolution VGA to Composite or S-Video Converter is a simple hardware solution that allows you to convert a VGA/PC video signal into a Composite or S-Video signal for use with a CRT or flat panel display.
>   [image: angle view]
>   [image: business-end #2]

Comment: +1 for the post. -1 to Sony for using that weird pinout. Took me ages to figure out, back in the day, when that was the only way to connect a lappy to an old CRT TV.